# Tag wiki excerpt improvements

Tags: feature-request, tagwiki

Whenever someone suggests a tag wiki excerpt, trusted users have a choice:

[image]

Clicking on "Improve" provides you with the opportunity to modify the suggested change with a motivation on what it is your changing (like with all edits). However, it does not show which tag you're editing or trying to improve.

This is not the case when you *create* a tag wiki (excerpt or description) for something, since the tag is clearly visible (stating **Editing tag wiki for {mytag}**).

I propose adding the **Editing tag wiki for {mytag}** as part of the "Improve" page as well.